# Access EIP and EBP via ucontext on OS X

Tags: c, linux, macos, freebsd

I am trying to port a tool to osx which is designed to run on linux and freebsd. There is a case in the program where access to the EIP and EBP is need. This is done via the ucontext.

So i added a case for __APPLE__ to place a suitable access to the ucontext struct.

```
 9887 #if defined(__FreeBSD__)
 9888         *paddr = uc->uc_mcontext.mc_eip;
 9889 #elif defined(__dietlibc__)
 9890         *paddr = uc->uc_mcontext.eip;
 9891 #elif defined(__APPLE__)
 9892         *paddr = uc->uc_mcontext.ss.eip;
 9893 #else
 9894         *paddr = uc->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_EIP];
 9895 #endif
```

But uc->uc_mcontext.ss.eip doesn't compile. Not sure how to access the EIP from the ucontext.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears the naming scheme changed in OS X 10.5, where it should be `uc->uc_mcontext->__ss.__eip`. On later versions this is `uc->uc_mcontext->__ss.__rip` for x86_64.

Found by quick [google search](http://www.google.co.il/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=com.ubuntu%3Aen-US%3Aunofficial&hs=sxR&q=uc_mcontext+osx&btnG=Search&meta=), refs:
[1](http://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-cvs/2007-March/031021.html), [2](http://gperftools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/m4/pc_from_ucontext.m4)

Comment: Thx, also __ss is an pointer. So it has to be:
uc->uc_mcontext->__ss.__eip;

Comment: It appears that it is now called "__rip", not "__eip", so it is now: uc->uc_mcontext->_ss.__rip;

Comment: it's `__eip` for 32bit processes (`i386`) and `__rip` for 64bit processes (`x86_64`). This only applies to Intel CPUs, on the iPhone/iPad/Apple Watch/Apple TV/... it'd be different.